# Which Broadcom driver to use for BCM43142 adapter in Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial xerus) LTS?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, broadcom

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu Xenial from Trusty, and am having trouble with my broadcom wireless adapter. I am currently using the bcmwl-kernel-source driver. The wifi works but keeps getting disconnected very frequently.

To troubleshoot I have tried to switch off the power management for the device. I have shifted from NetworkManager to wicd. I have tried the alternative, firmware-b43-installer, driver which doesn't work at all.

**I understand that a comprehensive answer ([Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868)) exists on installation of broadcom drivers but the information presented there might not be pertinent to Xenial.**

Comment: The answer doesn't have a solution for Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) LTS!!

Comment: @Abhinav Have you tried the solution?  Many times older solutions still work

Comment: For Xenial the solution is the same.

Comment: "might not be pertinent to Xenial" Did you even try it? It seems not.